# VisualStudio how to click button and do something

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnhello_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnhello.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("click anything", "error box", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
        MessageBox.Show("aborted")

    ElseIf DialogResult.Retry Then
        MessageBox.Show("retry done")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

in the Else If i want to do when i click Retry button display retry done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Select...Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) to handle the different [DialogResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult) values [MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show) can return:

```
Select Case MessageBox.Show("click anything", "error box", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    Case DialogResult.Abort
        MessageBox.Show("aborted")
    Case DialogResult.Retry
        MessageBox.Show("retry done")
    Case DialogResult.Ignore
        MessageBox.Show("ignore")
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this with the wrong approach. You have to store the dialog result in a variable and use that variable for checking. Try this :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnhello_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnhello.Click
        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("click anything", "error box", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = DialogResult.Abort Then
            MessageBox.Show("aborted")
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Retry Then
                MessageBox.Show("retry done")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```